# Unix - how to extract individual messages from a single file to different file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file, which contain lots of messages (not sure about the numbers) each message is start with tag `#START` and end with the tag `#END`. I want each and every messages in the main files should be saved in separate files i.e the number of messages in the main file should equal to the number of output files. No issues with the naming convention of the output files but it should be numbered.

Comment: I am new to sed and awk commands, really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I would say you should go read up on sed and awk then. This site is intended more to help with specific questions than as a general teaching site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily using AWK.

```
BEGIN {
    counter = 0;
    active = 0;
    current_file = "";
}

/^#START/ {
    counter += 1;
    current_file = "message" counter ".txt";
    active = 1;
    printf("") > current_file;
    next;
}

/^#END/ {
    active = 0;
    close(current_file);
    next;
}

(active) {
    print($0) > current_file;
}
```

What I did was implement a little finite state machine.  It has two states *active* and *inactive*.  It transitions from *inactive* to *active* upon reading `#SART` and back upon reading `#END`.  In the *active* state, it redirects each line it reads to the file named `current_file`.  At each transition from *inactive* to *active*, the counter `counter` (that is used to generate `current_file`) is incremented.

You can run this script (named `extract.awk`) on the file `inputs-log` via

```
$ awk -f extract.awk input.log
```

Using this sample input:

```
#START
This is the first message.
#END
This is not a message at all.
The second message is empty.
#START
#END
#START
This is the third message.
It is two lines long.
#END

#START
This is the fourth message.
#END
```

It would generate the files `message1.txt` to `message4.txt` that contain the lines between the corresponding tags in the file.

I recommend you read through the first chapters of [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to get more acquainted with AWK.